# CVaR Matlab Optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization, portfolio

I'm actually performing a CVaR optimization using Matlab. I use fmincon instead of linear programming (linprog).

I have my lower and upper bounds for 8 asset class and a specific linear inequality constraints; furthermore I use 10000 simulated returns (Scen_Rets) and 1000 bootstrapped variance-covariance matrix (useful for target volatility constraints). The objective function i've written is:

```
Riskfun=@(w) min(quantile(w * Scen_Rets',1-beta)+((1/size(Scen_Rets,1))*(1/(1-beta)))*(max(-w * Scen_Rets'-quantile(w * Scen_Rets',1-beta),0)));
```

Basically my code runs but I get the same asset weights for all the volatility constraints. I tried several risk function because I think my problem is in it. Could you please help me ?

Thanks, hope I've been clear.

Comment: Chances are it depends on your data... but I have no idea how it looks like. And I don't even know how your constraints look like. So who knows...

Comment: Data: historical quarterly returns of 8 asset class. On those i compute a var-cov matrix, and this matrix is then bootstrapped and used in the optimization along with Scen_Rets (10000 simulated return starting from a vector of expected returns).
Constraints: simply, the weight of particular assets cannot be greater than the 40% of another specific asset class.